# Oracle SQL loader -to load inconsistent date formats in same column

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g, oracle12c

My client has supplied 2 feed files of two different year to load into our database.The problem is cloumn(TIME_STAMP) receives data in two different formats.

For year 2019: The TIME_STAMP is received in format `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`

For year 2020: The column TIME_STAMP is received in format `YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS`

I have written a code in.ctl file like

```
"to_date(:TIME_STAMP, case when regexp_substr(:TIME_STAMP,'\w+',1,2)=regexp_substr(:TIME_STAMP,'\w+',1,2) then 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' else
'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' end)",
```

The problem is I am getting my 2019 file loaded but my 2020 giving

> "ORA-01843:Not a valid month"

Comment: Do you really need a solution that works for 3 different Oracle versions (two of them unsupported)?

Comment: Are you using `sqlldr` or SQL Developer?

Comment: No oracle 11g,12c enough

Comment: I am using Toad

Comment: is not it easier  for two files to write two scripts? If files have to be imported in the future, then you should discuss with the customer in what format the data will be sent. you will always have the problem if the customer sends the date in another format. The customers are usually very creative :)

Comment: We do you use a regexp? Should be enough to check the 3rd character. If / then MM/DD... else YYYY/ ...

Comment: @thomas Strub can you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
to_date(
    :TIME_STAMP, 
    case 
        when substr(:TIME_STAMP, 1, 4) = '2020' then 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' 
        else 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' 
    end
)
```

The logic is tom simply check the first 4 characters of the string; if it is `'2020'`, then we use the first sring format, else we use the other one.